# How to show rupee icon in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, fonts, font-awesome, ionic3

Currently Ionic [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/) do not have any icon for `rupee` sign.

Can anyone tell me how to display `rupee` sign using `ion-icon` ?

Comment: there no rupee icon for ionic now, you can use `img` or `font-awesome` for it.

Comment: You can also copy from ms word(symbol->rupee symbol).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Rupee symbol in ionicons font.
You can use [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>
```

Comment: Hi Vlad quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code to show rupee symbol **&#8377**:

```
<span>&#8377</span>
```

Comment: please insert ; after &#8377 otherwise it gives error "Errors during JIT compilation of template for PropertiesPage: Unable to parse entity "&#8377<" - decimal character reference entities must end with ";""

Comment: Thanks @AnjaniBarnwal it worked me but  now I changed the way I am using that symbol in my project I wanted to save that in database get get it dynamically but I couldnt do that for rupee and its working for other symbols like '$' etc., that would be more helpful to me if any one could clear my doubt